# Grails3.04, what is "f:table"?

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

1. grails 3.04
2. generate-all mydomain
3. index.gsp

what is "f:table"?
I can't find it in grails 3.04 document.
I can't find it in https://github.com/grails-fields-plugin/grails-fields.

What is this magic? How can I get to learn it?

I'm sorry, I don't have the ability to write English.

Translation support：http://fanyi.youdao.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tag `f:table` you are referring to comes from the `fields` plug-in, as you correctly noticed. It is used to render some (or all) properties of a list of beans (Domain Classes for example) as a table.

You pointed to the documentation of the fields plugin for Grails 2.x. The `fields` plug-in has been forked to make a version for Grails 3.x. Have a look here for the documentation: http://grails3-plugins.github.io/fields/snapshot/ref/Tags/table.html

Comment: Thank you very much.When I search it in https://grails.org/plugins, I didn't pay attention to the version of this.